# Can we get language and sub title language of vimeo video via api?

Tags: vimeo-api, video-subtitles

I am getting other data of vimeo video using the following api:

file_get_contents( 'https://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/' . $video_id. '.json' );

It shows required data as video images,duration,title,description and all but now I want the default language and sub title language of the specific video. The above api doesn't give the info.

Any idea about how to get language of vimeo video?

Any help/suggestions are welcome.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You're currently using the simple API, which doesn't provide the language.

The full Vimeo API provides this information, see a getting started guide [here](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/guides/start), the request you need to make is something like `'https://api.vimeo.com/videos/' . $video_id . '?fields=language'`